# can arduino on output mode sink current?

Tags: arduino-uno, pins

I have a arduino set below:

```
pinMode(1,OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(1,LOW);
```

Now, I am expecting 1.2mA current flow through the pin that is set as output. Is that accepted? If so, what it the max current a pin can sink?

The current comes from a pul up resistor on the line

note: I can't protect it with a diode.

Comment: [Arduino pin current limitations](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/ArduinoPinCurrentLimitations)

Comment: wouldn't `INPUT` allow more current?

Comment: yes it would, but Really what I'm doing in toggling between input and output LOW. The goal is to toggle the node from 0V to 3.3V.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I just found it.

from the arduno docs:

Atmega pins set aa output can source (provide positive current) or sink (provide negative current) up to 40 mA (milliamps) of current to other devices/circuits.

Comment: That's the absolute maximum rating. Recommended is 20mA

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can. [This blog post of mine will help to explain it](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/20/what-exactly-is-a-gpio-pin/).

In short:

> It’s all so simple now, isn’t it? The output pin is just like a switch that either connects it to 5V or to ground.

Answer (score 1):

> can arduino on output mode sink current?

yes.

> from the arduno docs:

the datasheet for the particular device is the best place for that answer.